# PHP: curl script fails

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

The task seemed simple.
The login (email) used for authentication must be passed in the login request parameter. In the request body (Body), the user password is passed as a string encoded in UTF-8.

Example request:

```
POST /auth/authenticate-by-pass?login=testlogin@testDomain.net HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.ru
Body: somepassword
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

If the request is successful, the response will contain a JSON object

**Tried to do like this:**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://somehost.ru/auth/authenticate-by-pass?login=mylogin@mydomain.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     "mypassword" ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain', 'Host: somehost.ru')); 
            
$result=curl_exec($ch);  
$php_obj = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($php_obj);
```

No result. Nothing is displayed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding what you need can be simply (please amend the headers to further suit your needs if necessary) :

```
$ch = curl_init();

$post = [
    'password' => 'xxxxxx'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somehost.ru/auth/authenticate-by-pass?login=mylogin@mydomain.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

$php_obj = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($php_obj);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: With "echo 'Error:'. Curl_error ($ ch);" displayed "Error: couldn't connect to host"

Comment: It seems to me that "mypassword" (somepassword) is incorrectly set (declared)

Comment: I have revised my answer, please replace the "xxxxxx" with your real password and retry.

Comment: Of course, I replaced "xxxxxx" with a real password (=

Comment: Passing `array` is correct; but `Error: couldn't connect to host` means `CURLOPT_URL` is wrong.

Comment: yes, please make sure that the url is correct. (e.g. somehost.ru may actually be some other domain ??)

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://somehost.ru/auth/authenticate-by-pass?login=mylogin@mydomain.com');`    changing "http" to "https" managed to achieve the following "BadPassword" error. I drip further)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. **Ken Lee** and everyone else thanks for the help.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$post = 'mypassword';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somehost.ru/auth/authenticate-by-pass?login=mylogin@mydomain.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

$php_obj = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($php_obj);

curl_close($ch);
```